# How to make a multi languages static site using gatsby-plugin-intl and gatsby markdown?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin-intl

I am trying to create a static site using gatsby which support two languages, my wish is all the content would be handle by markdown files.

I started with the plugin-gatsby-intl using this https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-intl/ -work great.

but i can not figure out how to use markdown, I guess because the gatsby-plugin-intl change the paths.
when i try to go to localhost:8000/blog it changes to localhost:8000/en/blog, and raise an error that in the template that the graphql query returned null.

I understand the problem but I cant manage to understand how to solve it.
I guess I need to make 2 markdowns file one for each lang and change the gatsby-node.js to manage correctly the paths but not sure how to do it.
The only information i found online was https://hiddentao.com/archives/2019/05/07/building-a-multilingual-static-site-with-gatsby
but after following his steps, I does not work

will appreciate any help

my gatsby-node.js:

```
const path = require(`path`)

exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/post.js`)

  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              path
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  // Handle errors
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }


  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    console.log("path:")
    console.log(node.frontmatter.path)
    createPage({
      path: node.frontmatter.path,
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      context: {}, // additional data can be passed via context
    })
  })
}
```

my template:

```
// src/templates/post.js
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

export default function Template({
  // this prop will be injected by the GraphQL query below.
    data, }) 
    {
    console.log(data)
    const { markdownRemark } = data // data.markdownRemark holds your post data
    const { frontmatter, html } = markdownRemark
    return (
      <div>
          <h1>{frontmatter.title}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }

  //$path which is a strings
  export const pageQuery = graphql`
    query ($path: String!) {
      markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
        html
        frontmatter {
          path
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `
  // )
  // .then(res => {
  //   console.log("result")
  //   // console.log(pageQuery.data)
  // })
```

and my blog.md:

```
---
path: "/blog"
date: "2019-05-04"
title: "My first blog post"
---


this is the my markdown
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-intl`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/locales`,
        languages: [`en-us`, `fr`, `pt-br`],
        defaultLanguage: `en-us`,
        redirect: false,
      },
    },
```

You can change redirect to false.